# How to avoid that the jQuery file loads after a custom js file? Sometimes I got $ not defined?

Tags: jquery, master-page

I have add in the master a jQuery registration and a custom js file in the header. After the custom js file I start running a function which is existing in my custom js file. Sometimes I got the error:

> $ not defined

It looks like it is depending on the performance. Maybe the order is not OK. How to avoid this error?

```
<head>
<script src="HERE SOME PATH/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="HERE SOME PATH/myCustom.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery.scrollDepth();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Perhaps you could pastebin/gist the source of the whole page? Like Ctrl+U or "View source"

Comment: Have you tried the no conflict syntax for jQuery calls? jQuery(window).load(function(){ StartCustomFunction });

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery(window).bind` instead of using `$(window).bind`.

See `jQuery.noConflict()`. Could other javascript libraries on your page be using the `$` variable?

`$` is just a variable that is used to alias jQuery and being a variable, anything could be assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `custom.js` and `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` at the bottom of the page, so that it loads first.

And also why not try loading your function like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  StartCustomFunction();
});
```